# Using SFINAE to detect if compiler supports std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<>> or not

Tags: c++

As you may know, even though C++20 added `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` specialization to the standard, most compilers does not support it yet. I was wondering if I can detect **whether** compiler supports this specialization or not using *SFINAE*.

I tried to write a code like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U=void>
struct details {
    details() {
        std::cout << "main\n";
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct details<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<std::atomic<T>>>> {
    details() {
        std::cout << "other\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    details<int> x;
    details<std::shared_ptr<int>> y; //<-- error here
}
```

But this does not work. I get an error for `details<std::shared_ptr<int>>` which says it cannot be created because `shared_ptr<int>` is not trivially constructible. I thought this error will cause that `other` specialization gets ignored and `main` will be selected, but it seems that I'm wrong.

Any idea how I can detect if this specialization is supported using *SFINAE*?

Comment: Does it not have a feature test macro?

Comment: [std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_always_lock_free) this should give you `true` only when `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` is implemented to be lock free.

Comment: @MarekR, so what? You can't use it unless it is supported.

Comment: @MarekR How I can get if it is supported?This comment is completely unrelated to question.

Comment: @chris I just checked and it seems `__cpp_lib_atomic_shared_ptr` should show if they are supported. But Isn't using *SFINAE* better rather than `#ifdef` if we can use it? In addition, based on my tests feature checking is not that reliable.

Comment: @Afshin, I would say it's not better than using the macros. Those feature test macros exist specifically for testing features. It's clear, concise, and leaves no room to doubt the intent. All SFINAE will do is make the reader ponder the reason that the tool specifically for that problem was not used. However, just because they're macros doesn't mean you have to use `#ifdef`. If you need separately compiled code, feel free. If you have a clear way to use it in normal code, go ahead. For example: `using type = std::conditional_t<feature_test, std_type, my_type>;`

Comment: Why is shared_ptr not trivially constructible at all? the default ctor doesn't appear to do anything non-trivial. I mean all reasonable implementations seem to use two raw pointers and they're all nullptr when default constructed. That should be trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not think it is ever possible with SFINAE. The checks are happening inside STL code with `static_assert` on the type within `std::atomic<>`, so overload is always viable for SFINAE. It's just that later during the game the `static_assert` fires.

This is not SFINAE-friendly technique, unfortunately. My reading of the standard tells me it is permissible, however, it could be considered "quality of implementation" issue.

Comment: Thanks for info. I was wondering why my code did not work. I guess I will use `__cpp_lib_atomic_shared_ptr` feature check even though it seems it is not that reliable.